# Can Maven be made less verbose?

Tags: maven, output, verbosity

Maven spews out far too many lines of output to my taste (I like the Unix way: no news is good news).

I want to get rid of all `[INFO]` lines, but I couldn't find any mention of an argument or config settings that controls the verbosity of Maven.

Is there no LOG4J-like way to set the log level?

Comment: With Maven 3.6.1 (April 2019, 10+ years later), `mvn --no-transfer-progress ...` (or `mvn -ntp` for shorts) should be an adequate solution. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56118170/6309).

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can try the [`-q` switch](http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-embedder/cli.html).

> `-q`,`--quiet` Quiet output - only show errors

Comment: @sheki: To clarify, this option does not disable logger debug messages - you need turn that off via your logger settings.  For example, if you're using logback, including a src/test/resources/logback-test.xml file in your project will let you customize your logging level to 'off' during the test phase.  This will clean everything up.

Comment: My problem is that `-q` is too quiet. I'm running maven under CI, and I want to see the steps it takes (to track progress), but the download indicators are making mess of the non-ANSI display. Is there a way to only turn off the download progress indicators?

Comment: @Guss: If you only want the Downloading/Downloaded messages to go away, use `-B` to enable batch mode (you should have that in your CI system anyways!), and then set `MAVEN_OPTS="-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn"` to kill the progress information for the downloads.

Comment: In maven 3.5.x I actually need to enable `--batch-mode` (`-B`) for the `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn` trick to work.

Comment: if you are inclined I've submitted a proposed solution compatible with interactive mode https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6605 , https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/239

Comment: `-q`  *kind of* works here (mvn 3.6.0, java 11.0.6) . Unfortunately I still get warnings like this: `WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.` etc.

Answer (score 43):

`-q` as said above is what you need. An alternative could be:

> `-B`,`--batch-mode`
> Run in non-interactive (batch) mode
> Batch mode is essential if you need to run Maven in a non-interactive, continuous integration environment. When running in non-interactive mode, Maven will never stop to accept input from the user. Instead, it will use sensible default values when it requires input.

And will also reduce the output messages more or less to the essentials.

Comment: it is used for non-interactive mode, which helps when automating runs

Answer (score 40):

> My problem is that -q is too quiet. I'm running maven under CI

With [Maven 3.6.1 (April 2019)](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.6.1/release-notes.html), you now have an **option to suppress the transfer progress when downloading/uploading in interactive mode**.

```
mvn --no-transfer-progress ....
```

> or in short:

```
mvn -ntp ... ....
```

That is what [Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279640/ray) proposed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069/can-maven-be-made-less-verbose/40535065#comment97499320_71086) with [MNG-6605](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6605) and [PR 239](https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/239).

Comment: This solution suppresses upload messages as well as downloads, which is usually not desired in a `deploy` task

Answer (score 26):

Official link :
https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

You can add in the **JVM** parameters :

```
-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=WARN
```

Beware of UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 7):

Use the -q or --quiet command-line options

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to get rid of the `[INFO]` messages you also could do:

```
mvn ... | fgrep -v "[INFO]"
```

To suppress **all** outputs (except errors) you could redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` with:

```
mvn ... 1>/dev/null
```

(This only works if you use `bash` (or similar shells) to run the Maven commands.)

Answer (score 3):

The existing answer help you filter based on the log-level using `--quiet`.  I found that many INFO messages are useful for debugging, however the downloading artifact log messages such as the following were noisy and not helpful.

```
Downloading: http://nexus:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml
```

I found this solution:

https://blogs.itemis.com/en/in-a-nutshell-removing-artifact-messages-from-maven-log-output

```
mvn clean install -B -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
```

Answer (score 2):

Maven 3.1.x uses SLF4j for logging, you can find instructions how to configure it at https://maven.apache.org/maven-logging.html

In short: Either modify `${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/logging/simplelogger.properties`, or set the same properties via the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable.

For example: setting `MAVEN_OPTS` to `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cl‌​i.transfer.Slf4jMave‌​nTransferListener=wa‌​rn` configures the logging of the batch mode transfer listener, and `-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=warn` sets the default log level.

Answer (score 0):

I've been successful in the past to mute individual warnings e.g. for `com.example.X`, by using this plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.com.example.X</name>
                        <value>error</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The benefit over [setting the system property externally as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41002277/521799) is that it automatically applies to all builds / executions.