# Simplify NetBeans output

Tags: java, netbeans

My issue is that I recently updated NetBeans from 11.3 to 12.0 and the output now shows a lot of details that I don't need. Any ideas how to fix it?
For example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Test");
 }
}
```

And the output is

```
cd C:\Users\user\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Java; "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.1" cmd /c "\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.0\\netbeans\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.cmd\" -Dexec.args=\"-classpath %classpath Test\" -Dexec.executable=\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-14.0.1\\bin\\java.exe\" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans-12.0\\netbeans\\java\\maven-nblib\\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec"
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------< ayp:Java >------------------------------
Building Java 1.0-SNAPSHOT
--------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ Java ---
Test
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time:  1.183 s
Finished at: 2020-06-23T14:33:48-03:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I'd like to change it so that it shows like it did before, it'd be something like this:

```
Test
BUILD SUCCESS
Total time:  1.183 s
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems not to be related to NetBeans 12. It is related to type of project. I am still on 11.3 and I have similar logs as well.

You created maven project, that's why you have such output when you build the project. If you don't want that, create project by  different template. I guess you can create ant based project. Not sure about grade. Such logs is there only because of building the application. It won't be present if you run the application without NetBeans.

Another option is to change maven log level or use quiet option as described below:

[Can Maven be made less verbose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71069/can-maven-be-made-less-verbose/40535065#40535065)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a difference between versions of NetBeans (although there are some Maven-related output differences).

This is the difference between a Maven project (more verbose) and an Ant project (less verbose).

`File > New Project > Java with Maven`

vs.

`File > New Project > Java with Ant`